# View Content:Path Rewrite Result doesn't update

Tags: views, nodes

The Content:Path is used to create a Read More button, that redirects the user to another page from View.

It had a previous Rewrite Result of:

```
<a href="[path]" class="readmore"> Read More </a>
```

I want the change the string to See More, so I thought it would be a easy change. Boy was I wrong.

No matter what I input into the Rewrite Results output field, it will always default to display Read More (with it's class and href). I can write gibberish, and the View wouldn't show what I wrote and default back to Read More (though preview does display accordingly).

The only time I can get it to display different is when I leave the field empty, or disable Rewrite Result functionality, which it defaults to the content path.

Can anyone explain this weird behaviour? I've done some checks if there's a hook influencing the view, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you have other options enabled that might affect this, like the `Output this field as a link` option?

Comment: Hi @prkos, where should I be looking for this option?

Comment: It's just below the Override output area, in the same collapsible fieldset "Rewrite results". Can you explain about the bit that preview displays accordingly? It displays changes? But not when visiting the page? Then it may be some hook in your default theme.

Comment: You know when you edit a view, below the options is a preview of what would be displayed (without css applied).  In that preview, it correctly shows See More. 
But when I save the changes of the View and view the actual page, it still displays Read More. 
I do not have that option enabled. Or anything I could tell is important.

Comment: The Views Preview is using the admin theme, that is why it seems to you that "there is no CSS applied". There is CSS, only from the admin theme, and not from your default theme. You probably have something in your default theme affecting this. To test, apply a different theme to your site, usualy the original Garland is used to test theme bugs. If it works in Garland, then you know it's your theme causing the problem.

Comment: Set my default theme to Garland and navigated to that page. Still it's showing Read Now :\

Comment: Have you cleared cache? Are you using some module for it? https://www.drupal.org/project/read_more BTW: [Path field deprecation and backwards compatibility for existing views](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2953116). What D version? Please add all new info to your question, cases clearly explaining what happens under what conditions.

Comment: I have indeed cleared cache, drupal and browser. 
I am not using any modules for this, as it's simply overriding what content:path would be, and using the original content:path as the href redirect. 
Drupal version is 7.39, with all security patch manually implemented (this is due to server php version which I don't have control of).